# getting "implicit declaration of function 'fcloseall' is invalid in C99" when compiling to gnu99

Tags: c, c99, clang

Consider the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fatal(const char* message){
 /*
  Prints a message and terminates the program.
  Closes all open i/o streams before exiting.
 */
 printf("%s\n", message);
 fcloseall();
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I'm using clang 2.8 to compile: `clang -Wall -std=gnu99 -o <executable> <source.c>`

And get: `implicit declaration of function 'fcloseall' is invalid in C99`

Which is true, but i'm explicitly compiling to gnu99 [which should support fcloseall()], and not to c99.
Although the code runs, I don't like to have unresolved warnings when compiling.
How can i solve this?

**Edit**: corrected tipo.

Comment: I cut and pasted your code and got an expected link error about `main` not being defined, but no implicit declaration error. Are you sure your error comes from the version of the code that you have shown?

Comment: What happens if you declare it yourself? I.e. put `int fcloseall(void);` somewhere.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to call `fcloseall`. It's a useless nonstandard function. `exit` already safely closes all files, and if your program will be ending with `_Exit` or `exec` instead, `fflush(NULL)` will flush all files which is just as good and standards-conformant.

Comment: @R: Ok, that is usefull information -thank you. I'll adapt my code correspondingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include non-standard extensions when you include standard headers you need to define the appropriate feature test macro. In this case `_GNU_SOURCE` should work.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
```

This is independent of `-std=gnu99` which enables language extensions, not library extensions.

Comment: @Emanuel Ey: Are you sure? It works for me(tm). Tried without `_GNU_SOURCE` and got the same error as you, inserted `#define _GNU_SOURCE` and the error went away.

Comment: Ok, got it -you where right. I had `#define _GNU_SOURCE` at beginnig of this (tools.c) file, and not in its parent (which is the one i'm actually compiling. Thanks!

Comment: Also: i can omit `-std=gnu99`.

Comment: -1 Never define `_GNU_SOURCE` inside your code, use `-D_GNU_SOURCE` instead!

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Can you explain or provide a supporting reference? Thanks.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: nice. already moved `_GNU_SOURCE` from code to my makefile. Thanks.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be  Strongly disagree.  If the code relies on features of a particular standard, that reliance should be clearly stated in the source code.

Comment: @Charles Defining `_GNU_SOURCE` inside your code will apply only to includes following the definition. This can very easily lead to multiple different versions of the same header being included into your code. Using compiler flag will prevent this problem.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I can see how you might cause problems if you are not careful, and I see advantages to both approaches, but "never" suggests there is some fundamental problem which I don't see. GNU C Library manual seems happy to recommend `#define`: http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: All feature test macros need to be defined at the top of a source file before any includes. Following this rule is not difficult nor error-prone.

Comment: It should be further noted that there's no legitimate use for `fcloseall` any more than there's a legitimate use for a hypothetical `freeall` function. Deallocating "all" resources of a given type is a programming error; they should be deallocated individually by the code that owns them or not at all. `fflush(0)` would be a perfectly safe and portable way to ensure all data is written without violating this principle, but the subsequent call to `exit` already does the right thing anyway, so this whole question is a matter of Cargo Cult Programming...

Comment: @R..: How about `#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE`/`#error Need to define _GNU_SOURCE in makefile`/`#endif`?.  That would seem to make clear the reliance upon the macro, without the hazards that might arise if it was defined within the source.

Answer (score 1):

Here in the `man` page of `fcloseall()`

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 
#include <stdio.h>
```

You have to define macros _GNU_SOURCE is you snippet, along with `stdio.h` header. `_GNU_SOURCE` is a feature test macros which is used to create portable application.